# Unable to add second array object value into first array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

hi i have two arrays i want to merge two arrays, can any one help one please, i have for used for loop pushing that values but its creating duplicates.

```
  const firstArray = [
    {
      first: "01",
      data: [{ id: "012345" }, { id: "0123456" }, { id: "0123457" }]
    },
    {
      first: "02",
      data: [{ id: "9998989" }, { id: "1223" }, { id: "345666" }]
    },
    {
      first: "03",
      data: [{ id: "567888" }, { id: "2345" }, { id: "09876" }]
    }
  ];
  const secondArray = [{ data: "abc" }, { data: "efg" }, { data: "hij" }];
```

I need result like this can any one,

```
[
  {
    first: "01",
    data: [
      { id: "012345", data: "abc" },
      { id: "0123456", data: "efg" },
      { id: "0123457", data: "hij" },
    ],
  },
  {
    first: "02",
    data: [
      { id: "9998989", data: "abc" },
      { id: "1223", data: "efg" },
      { id: "345666", data: "hij" },
    ],
  },
  {
    first: "03",
    data: [
      { id: "567888", data: "abc" },
      { id: "2345", data: "efg" },
      { id: "09876", data: "hij" },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Can you show what the expected output would look like if `secondArray` has `[{ data: "abc" }, { data: "123" }, { data: "xyz" }]` instead. Its currently unclear how the data from the `secondArray` maps to the first. Would you also be able to add your attempt using the `for` loop

Comment: Share the code that you tried with output

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-nwm0r?file=/demo.js:447-865

Comment: the above is the link of code sand box,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using nested for loops to build your array from scratch, you can instead use two `.map()` methods. One for mapping your outer objects in `firstArray` to new objects with a new `data` value, and another for mapping your `data` to a merged version from the data in `secondArray`. To merge, you can take the corresponding object from `secondArray` using the index and then using the spread syntax to merge both objects together:

```js
const firstArray = [ { first: "01", data: [{ id: "012345" }, { id: "0123456" }, { id: "0123457" }] }, { first: "02", data: [{ id: "9998989" }, { id: "1223" }, { id: "345666" }] }, { first: "03", data: [{ id: "567888" }, { id: "2345" }, { id: "09876" }] } ];

const secondArray = [{ data: "abc" }, { data: "efg" }, { data: "hij"}];
const res = firstArray.map(obj => ({
  ...obj,
  data: obj.data.map((inner, i) => ({...inner, ...secondArray[i]}))
}));
console.log(res);
```

To fix your current implementation, you can create two arrays, one outside of your for loop like you currently are already doing, and then one inside your first for loop. The inner array will represent your new data array, which you can then update for your current object:

```js
const firstArray = [{ first: "01", data: [{ id: "012345" }, { id: "0123456" }, { id: "0123457" }] }, { first: "02", data: [{ id: "9998989" }, { id: "1223" }, { id: "345666" }] }, { first: "03", data: [{ id: "567888" }, { id: "2345" }, { id: "09876" }] } ]; const secondArray = [{ data: "abc" }, { data: "123" }, { data: "xyz" }];

const emptyArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
  const data = firstArray[i].data;
  const dataArray = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    const newObject = {
      ...data[j],
      ...secondArray[j]
    };
    dataArray.push(newObject);
  }
  emptyArray.push({...firstArray[i], data: dataArray});
}
console.log(emptyArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the `data` array and second array size are same. Use nested `map` method calls to build the aggregation

```js
const firstArray = [
  {
    first: "01",
    data: [{ id: "012345" }, { id: "0123456" }, { id: "0123457" }],
  },
  {
    first: "02",
    data: [{ id: "9998989" }, { id: "1223" }, { id: "345666" }],
  },
  {
    first: "03",
    data: [{ id: "567888" }, { id: "2345" }, { id: "09876" }],
  },
];
const secondArray = [{ data: "abc" }, { data: "efg" }, { data: "hij" }];

const output = firstArray.map(({ first, data }) => ({
  first,
  data: data.map((item, i) => ({ ...item, ...secondArray[i] })),
}));

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve the result using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in js

```js
const firstArray = [
  {
    first: "01",
    data: [{ id: "012345" }, { id: "0123456" }, { id: "0123457" }],
  },
  {
    first: "02",
    data: [{ id: "9998989" }, { id: "1223" }, { id: "345666" }],
  },
  {
    first: "03",
    data: [{ id: "567888" }, { id: "2345" }, { id: "09876" }],
  },
];
const secondArray = [{ data: "abc" }, { data: "efg" }, { data: "hij" }];

const result = firstArray.map((obj) => ({
  ...obj,
  data: obj.data.map((o, i) => ({ ...o, ...secondArray[i] })),
}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your desired result you should do something like this:

```
let emptyArrray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
    const dataa = firstArray[i].data;
    for (let j = 0; j < dataa.length; j++) {
      
        // console.log(secondArray[i]);
        let newObject = {
          ...secondArray[j],
          ...dataa[j]
        };
        emptyArrray.push(newObject);
      
    }
  }
```

in your code you are getting 3*9 long array because you use nestled loop where you shouldn't, you just run over the array once, and add members from array two,
also you used

```
  ...secondArray[i],
  ...dataa[i]
```

instead of

```
  ...secondArray[j],
  ...dataa[j]
```

when incrementing **j** in the for loop